# Cruce de dos tablas mediante columnas, teniendo un select distinct anidado

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando hacer un cruce de inf entre dos tablas, además de un **select distinct**.

Presento diagrama de las tablas y columnas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> La tabla "Instituto" tiene la columna Id_Alumno
>
> La tabla "GrupoA" tiene las columnas Alumnos y Calificación
>
> La tabla "GrupoB" tiene las columnas Alumnos y Calificación

Se debe cruzar la tabla "instituto" con la tabla "grupoA" atraves de la columna Alumnos con el objetivo de extraer la calificación que conforma cada alumno, Los alumnos que no se encuentran en la tabla de  "grupoA" se deben buscar en la tabla  "GrupoB" con el objetivo de extraer las calificaciones de todos los alumnos.

Tengo las siguientes consultas pero estan por separado y no entiendo muy bien como uniry que sea solamente una. Para hacer el cruce tengo esta consulta

```
select Alumnos, Calificacion
from GrupoB a 
left join Instituto b  a.Alumno = b.ID_Alumno
group by Alumnos,Calificacion
```

Ahora para buscar en la tabla de Grupo B los alumnos que no estan en la tabla de GrupoA, se tiene la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT Alumnos FROM GrupoA
UNION DISTINCT SELECT Alumnos FROM GrupoB
```

Alguna sugerencia de como unir estas dos consultas y tener un resultado. Por favor

Comment: ¿`Alumnos` es una columna?

Comment: @Sal Hola, Si Alumnos es columna

Comment: ¿Es posible compartir un diagrama de las tablas y sus conexiones?

Comment: @an-tet Si, Claro, voy a editar la pregunta con el diagrama

Comment: Espero la solución propuesta te sea de utilidad y si es así la valores marcándola como la respuesta y dándole un punto.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el **UNION ALL** para unir los resultados pero ambos creo deben tener los mismos capos si no estoy mal igual te dejo una **DOC** al final y un ejemplo de como creo funciona

```
    SELECT Alumnos, Calificacion
    from GrupoB a 
    left join Instituto b  a.Alumno = b.ID_Alumno
    group by Alumnos,Calificacion
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Alumnos, Calificacion FROM GrupoA
    UNION DISTINCT SELECT Alumnos FROM GrupoB
```

**Doc:** https://www.sqlshack.com/es/revision-ejemplos-y-uso-de-sql-union/

Espero te sea de ayuda, no profundizo mas porque no soy capaz de replicar tu ejemplo, no veo las relaciones totalmente en tus diagramas seria genial si compartieras detalles de lo que obtienes y como estan tus tablas conectadas entre ellas eso facilita dar una respuesta.